# client order detail page total due issue magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, order-grid

i am using magento 1.9 i have created a rule for if order price is less then $5000 add shipping charges $10. its working fine but what i need is when the rule is applied than plus $10 into total due check attached image [image: order sample]

**above image i have attached is client order detail page**
other pages like cart, invoices are working fine

as you can see above image is what i am getting. but how do i plus $10 into $3,570 total due?.

I am new in Magento but i know development stuff very well but i couldn't find any solution so i need help to achieve this.

i do some more research and find totals.php

**totals.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml order totals block
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Totals//Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize order totals array
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals
     */
    protected function _initTotals()
    {
        parent::_initTotals();
        $this->_totals['paid'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'paid',
            'strong'    => true,
            'value'     => $this->getSource()->getTotalPaid(),
            'base_value'=> $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalPaid(),
            'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Total Paid'),
            'area'      => 'footer'
        ));
        $this->_totals['refunded'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'refunded',
            'strong'    => true,
            'value'     => $this->getSource()->getTotalRefunded(),
            'base_value'=> $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalRefunded(),
            'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Total Refunded'),
            'area'      => 'footer'
        ));
        $this->_totals['due'] = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'due',
            'strong'    => true,
            'value'     => $this->getSource()->getTotalDue(),
            'base_value'=> $this->getSource()->getBaseTotalDue(),
            'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Total Due'),
            'area'      => 'footer'
        ));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

i duplicated total paid code block and replace as it below:

```
   $this->_totals['charges'] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'code'      => 'charges',
        'strong'    => true,
        'value'     => $this->getSource()->getShippingCharges(),
        'base_value'=> $this->getSource()->getBaseShippingCharges(),
        'label'     => $this->helper('sales')->__('Shipping Charges'),
        'area'      => 'footer'
    ));
```

after added into totals.php i though this would work this maybe plus $10 into $3,570 but it work some way but showing value $0. maybe it does work if its get value
i need just right parameters or filename.